# How to backup a networked drive?

Tags: networking, backup, external-hard-drive

I have a networked drive (Iomega Media Drive). 
To be safe in case the drives crashes, I've decided to buy an additional networked drive (WD MyBook World).
Now, how do I backup one onto the other continuously?

The WD drive came with a backup software (trial version, they didn't say that when i bought it), however it doesn't allow me to select a networked drive, only local drives.

How do I backup a NETWORKED DRIVE ONTO A NETWORKED DRIVE?

Thanks

Comment: This question type has been asked alot.  Try searching for rsync on SU, or check out  http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Answer (score 0):

There are many options.

You could buy a commercial product such as one by [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/).  This will probably be the simplest as the expense of a few dollars.  Just create a scheduled backup task that backs up one drive onto the other drive.  You could use drive images or just clone one drive to the other.

You could find a free backup program and try that.  I have no experience with these so I can't recommend one, but [here is a simple list of free backup programs](http://download.cnet.com/windows/backup-software/) to get you started.

Or, you can write your own and run it as a scheduled task.  Assuming you're using Windows, you could write a batch file as simple as:

```
xcopy X:\ Y:\ /e /i /y
```

or

```
robocopy X:\ Y:\ /COPYALL /MIR
```

which will copy everything from the X: drive onto the Y: drive (assuming you have the drives mapped as X: and Y:, of course).  I'd recommend the `robocopy` option (you'll need to install it using the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) if you're not on Vista or later) since it has more options available to you if you want to customize how it works, and it behaves better copying over the network.